# How time complexity of std::nth_element in C++ is linear O(n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

time complexity is mentioned in links :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdnth_element-in-cpp/
cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/

Comment: I removed the `stl` tag since the link you posted is for the C++ standard library. See [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library).

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking how that algorithm is implemented, or are you asking whether the quoted time complexity is correct?